# How to dock a tool window when it open for the first time in vsix?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I have created tool window in VSIX, now i need to dock that when it open for the first time as per the desired position we set and next time if user moves the tool window it should persist with that position as visual studio doing already.

The below code i have tried, but it always docking to bottom position. how can i change and where i should write to set programmatically.

code snippet:

```
ToolWindowPane window = this.package.FindToolWindow(typeof(ToolWindow1), 0, true);
if ((null == window) || (null == window.Frame))
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot create tool window");
}

IVsWindowFrame windowFrame = (IVsWindowFrame)window.Frame;
windowFrame.SetProperty((int)__VSFPROPID.VSFPROPID_FrameMode, (int)VSFRAMEMODE.VSFM_Dock);
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(windowFrame.Show());
```

Comment: I think you need this: [Properties of ProvideToolWindowAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.providetoolwindowattribute?view=visualstudiosdk-2022#properties)

Comment: yeah i used providetoolwindow attribute only. But in the place of Orientation argument in this, i need to use my custom values and its accepting only constant. how can i fix this .is there any way to add our values in the place of orientation?

Comment: Hi Joan, you can take a look of my answer, I think this behavior should be unable to achieve, because the official document emphasized that 'You cannot specify that a tool window is docked by default. '

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the correct way to achieve this is to use 'Properties of ProvideToolWindowAttribute'.

But I notice this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.vsdockstyle?view=visualstudiosdk-2022&redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks

[image]

> You cannot specify that a tool window is docked by default. However,
> you can specify that it will dock when its title bar is
> double-clicked.

So the situation you encountered is expected, as it is already mentioned in the official document.